# How to set the session variable onclick in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I want to set session on clicking of link so after login user will redirect to last visited page.

for example:

Step1 : user opened home page.(seesion url set to home page

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

step2 : Next in new tab user will open contact page (again session variable reset)

step3: user will come to home page and click to login link.(session not set because no reload of page)

step4: after login user will redirect to contact page.

but here i want user to be redirect where user clicked the link for login.

i tried with following code but it not working for me.

PHP code:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url=$_SESSION['url'];
```

HTML code

```
<div class="gallery_div"> 
    <p>
      Please Click <strong><a href="login.php?link=<?php echo $url; ?>" style="color:#993b05"> here </a></strong>to login

    </p></div>
```

In login page

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['link']))
{
$_SESSION['url'] = $_GET['link'];

}
```

when redirect this page it coming with parameter and so page not found is coming. because only login.php is there.

can any one help me on this.

Comment: As problem: you not open session. Try call `session_start` before write to session.

Comment: sorry in post i forgot. but in code used.

Comment: Where is `$url`defined?

Comment: Do you have the correct url when you click the login link? try to echo the `$_GET['link']` and the `$_SESSION['url']`. If you have it right you may need to redirect with `header('Location:'.$_SESSION['url']);`. Otherwise check if you reset or destroy your session on wrong positions.

Comment: Try to print_r($_SERVER) to see what is the right variable for last page because on localhost it may not work as on a specific domain.

Comment: here i am getting problem in passing <a href="login.php?link=<?php echo $url; ?> here i have only login page. so please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to use session to achieve this. You can redirect the user based on $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. This will tell you the last visited page. You can even add some filtration here as needed.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!='' && stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'mydomain.com')!==false){
   header('location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Hello $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] give last visited page "mydomain.com/display.php?ID=781" but here i have like "mydomain.com/display.php?ID=781#about" so how to get this #about is menu tabs in that page like about,share,setting and all. depending on user select that need to be go.. please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['url']`  is not the same as `$url`

In your html, change `<?php echo $url; ?>` to  `<?php echo $_SESSION['url']; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Two pages required.First one is for calling (on-click) a session and other sets the value of session through ajax.

```
< a href="#" onclick="setsession()" style="color:#993b05"> Login </a>
<br/>
<script>
<br/>
function setsession(){<br/>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  <br/>
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari<br/>
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); <br/> 
  }<br/>
else<br/>
  {// code for IE6, IE5<br/>
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");<br/>
  }<br/>
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()<br/>
  {<br/>
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)<br/>
    {<br/>
    document.getElementById("scat").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;<br/>
    }<br/>
  }<br/>
<br/>
xmlhttp.open("post","setsession.php",true);// calls a page  where u can set session <br/>
xmlhttp.send();<br/>
}<br/>
</script><br/>
if(isset($_GET['link']))<br/>
{<br/>
$_SESSION['url'] = $_GET['link'];<br/>
<br/>
}<br/>
header("Location:redirect.php");<br/>
```